# Convert canvas image in webpage to pdf using flying saucer

Tags: pdf, canvas, html, flying-saucer

I am using [Flying Saucer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html) to generate **pdf** from **webpages**. I came across a problem. Problem is **how to print canvas images in pdf** using **flying saucer**. Is there any other way, i can **convert canvas images** to pdf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to print canvas images into pdf using xhtmlrenderer, would be to convert these images into some format  FS could understand. There is a Javascript method that converts the canva images into some static format that FS could use, 
please take a look at https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image

Hope this would help :)